# Initialize Postgres db in Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=anime
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

This configuration starts a Postgres database. In volume I defined init.sql, which should set up a table:

```
CREATE TABLE anime ( 
  anime_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT
);
```

Then, I would like to fill the Postgres database with data from the CSV file.

I tried to add another volume to docker-compose:

```
 - ./preload.sql:/preload/preload.sql
```

with that script:

```
copy anime FROM 'docker/data/AnimeList.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

The CSV file is located in the `data` folder, on the same level as `docker-compose.yml`.

But it is not working. The database is created correctly, but it doesn't have the table and data. When I connect to Docker container, run `'psql` command and try to get `anime` table, I get the following error:

```
Did not find any relation named "anime".
```

My question is: how to preload the Postgres container with the CSV data file in docker-compose?

Comment: Do you have any error? Can you share the final docker-compose.yml file you're using?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I managed to make it work using custom `Dockerfile`, here's my solution:

### Project structure

```
data/
  datasource.csv
db/
  scripts/
    1_init.sql
    2_copy.sql
  Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

### Files

1. `CSV` file is located in `data` folder inside of the project.
2. In the project folder there is the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

   ```
   version: '3.3'

   services:
     db:
       build: ./db
       container_name: postgres
       ports:
         - "5431:6666"
       environment:
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
         - POSTGRES_DB=db_name
       volumes:
         - ./data:/data
   ```
3. `Dockerfile` contains:

   ```
   FROM postgres:alpine
   ADD scripts/1_init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   ADD scripts/2_copy.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   RUN chmod a+r /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
   EXPOSE 6666
   ```
4. `1_init.sql` body:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE table_name
   (
      --statement body
   );
   ```
5. And `2_copy.sql`:

   ```
   COPY table_name FROM '/data/datasource.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
   ```

### Explanation

`1_init.sql` creates the DB table, **it has to have the same column names as in CSV file**. `2_copy.sql` is responsible for copying data from the CSV to postgres.

`Dockerfile` uses postgres image and copies all `*.sql` files to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. Later, all files are executed in alphanumerical order, that's why `*.sql` files start with digits. Finally, port `6666` is exposed.

`docker-compose.yml` builds the `Dockerfile` from `db` folder and make it accessible through `5431` port. As environmental properties basic postgres properties are used. And at the end `data` folder with CSV file is copied to the container.

Comment: this was an awesome answer and should have more upvotes. Solved my problem!

Comment: You simply could have mounted the SQL files to where you copied them in your image. Another option would be to use a psql-client-Docker-Image.